# geom_bar position width issue in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a fun way to learn `ggplot2` I'm trying to reproduce the fivethirtyeight
[barplot on bob ross paintings](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/a-statistical-analysis-of-the-work-of-bob-ross/). I've attached the reprex of
my attempted code below:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

# OPTION 1 - Download raw data directly from source
ross_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/bob-ross/elements-by-episode.csv"
ross_dat <- read_csv(file = ross_url)

ross_tidy <- ross_dat %>%
                gather(key = tag, value = indicator, APPLE_FRAME:WOOD_FRAMED)
new_tag_fmt <- function(str){
    str_replace_all(string = str, pattern = "_",
                             replacement = " ") %>%
        str_trim() %>%
        str_to_title() %>%
        return()
}

tot_episodes <- ross_tidy %>% select(EPISODE) %>% n_distinct()
ross_tidy2 <- ross_tidy %>%
                group_by(tag) %>%
                summarize(total = sum(indicator)) %>%
                ungroup() %>%
                mutate(tag = as.factor(new_tag_fmt(str = tag)),
                              perc = round(total/tot_episodes, 2),
                              perc_fmt = scales::percent(perc)) %>%
                arrange(desc(total)) %>%
                filter(total >= 5)


ggplot(ross_tidy2, aes(x = reorder(tag, perc), y = perc)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#198DD1",
                      width = 2, position = "dodge") +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = "The Paintings of Bob Ross",
                  subtitle = "Percentage containing each element") +
    geom_text(data = ross_tidy2, nudge_y = 0.02, angle = 270,
                           aes(reorder(tag, total), y = perc, label = perc_fmt),
                       family = "Courier", color = "#3E3E3E") +
    scale_color_fivethirtyeight("cyl") +
    theme_fivethirtyeight() +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                   axis.line = element_blank(),
                   axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                   axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                   plot.title = element_text(size = 18, hjust=-0.5),
                   plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 14, hjust=-0.5),
                   axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12))
#> Warning: position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-14 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

The problem here is I keep getting the warning:

> ### Warning: position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals

Could anyone please show me the issue in the code, the `tag` variable
is a factor i.e. categorical so I thought the above should work.

NOTE: Full credit to fivethirtyeight for providing the data to reproduce their work!

Comment: You set width as 2, but bar width is measured as a percentage. Having a width of 1 would give you bars that are flush side by side. The default is 0.9. And as noted below, you don't need to dodge bars if you only have one group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bar widths are too large, so it's tough for them to "dodge" each other. I set the width to 1 and didn't get the error.

Comment: thanks for your help. I changed the code to be `ggplot2::geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#198DD1", 
                      width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))` and the warning goes away. But the final chart still does not have any spacings between bars. Or more importantly the chart does not stretch out like the fivethirtyeight one. Any ideas how to make it look more like that?

Comment: Did you try removing the "width" requirement and just setting "position" to "dodge?" Does that give you the effect you want?

Comment: Good idea. It does now separate the bars but the plot is very congested. Is there a way to vertically increase (i.e. stretch) the ggplot2 plot size the way the original graphic is? I know this can be done when saving, but in displaying I'm not sure

Comment: I don't know what you're using to display. I use RStudio and it's simply enough just to go to the corner of the image, click and drag to resize the image.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should have clarified this. I know sizing can be done manually. I  am creating an Rmd and rendering to HTML so the plot should be sized similarly to the source in HTML using code alone not user re-sizing. Again this is just to see how far I can push Rmd + ggplot2 to reproducing a cool graphic. And yes, I'm using RStudio to write and knit the Rmd to HTML

Comment: Just change the `width` argument to <1 ? - not the one within `position_dodge`. You actually also do not need position_dodge at all for your plot.

Comment: Another small comment - you don't necessarily need to always specify the package with x::

Comment: There's a host of ways to resize images in markdown. See:
https://sebastiansauer.github.io/figure_sizing_knitr/

Comment: Thanks @Tjebo and Brian for your helpful comments. Yes changing the width <1 does work (as does removing the width). I feel that the chart does not look quite as elegant as the one in the article after these changes (which is much more nicely spaced and the percentage annotations are readable). Regardless I learnt from these comments and will mark this as the required answer for now.

Comment: Readability of the annotation is a matter of font size with respect to figure size. you specify the font size with `theme` and the plot size is in my workflow usually defined when saving the plot, e.g. as pdf

Answer (score 2):

```
ross_tidy2 %>%
 ggplot(data = ., aes(x = reorder(tag, perc), y = perc)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",width = 0.9) +
  coord_flip()
```

is enough
you don't need position_dodge (you don't have several groups)

[image]